# Why must I use window.onload to draw an image to the canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to draw an image to the canvas but the code:

```
ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);
```

doesn't work by itself. It was pointed out to me that its because the html wasn't loaded when that line was executed. I was suggested this code, which works:

```
window.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);
}
```

I don't understand why this works though because I thought a similar solution would be to place the script tag below the body which I did but that doesn't work. Can someone explain this to me in a way a toddler could understand.

Comment: You don't place it below the body but at the end of body, right before `</body>`. If you do this, it should work without wrapping it. Post your code though, we can't fix code we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, in a web page the JavaScript executes first, then the text in body loads later. So placing `<script>` tag anywhere syntactically won't matter as it will load first. The `ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);` runs before the page has even rendered so you cannot see the output.

`Window.onload` is a method which runs the function inside it after the whole document has rendered. After it is rendered and you run your function you will see the desired output.

Comment: thank you i did not know that the script always runs first

Comment: Question though, why doesn't this show up in the console? How can i debug this if there's no error thrown?

Comment: Also if what you said is true why don't i run into this same problem with other projects, like this calculator https://jsfiddle.net/tmLrs9wy/7/ the JS is loaded first yet it identifies and alters the html tags?

Comment: ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0); takes image as one of it's parameters. Here the image is ground. Image tags have to load a full size image, while as other tags have to only load up the text which is quite fast. So actually the ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0); has not to specifically wait for the whole window to load, you can also fire it on your image.onload and it will work too. Canvas needs a reference image and if it isn't there it will draw nothing.Image.onload fires when image is loaded and canvas draws the image.  Hope this clears out your doubt.

Comment: If this clears your doubt, mark the answer as correct so it can help others too. thank you.

Comment: Thank you it makes sense to me now, much appreciated